# Comprehensive Dictionary of Auto parts

Tags: part-identification

Does anyone know of a website, list, book, etc that provides a comprehensive list of auto parts, description and synonymous words?

Update: An example for my Jeep I just had the ignition pickup replaced. However in my Haynes Jeep book that part is no where listed. After much research I have found that its referenced as camshaft position sensor (in the book) and on some sites its referenced as a distributor switch plate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_auto_parts).

That isn't a joke. That list will actually get you a fair ways towards being able to tell a mechanic something useful. For example, sometimes it's not immediately obvious if you're looking at a catalytic converter or a resonator. However, given that vocabulary list, you'd at least be able to say "this part is rattling" and when the mechanic agrees that the heat shield on your cat is loose, you both feel like you solved the problem together.

Comment: Great thought, Bob. I hadn't thought of it that way, but you are exactly right. And to think, I was ready to put a closed vote on this question.

Comment: Yes there are sites out there that list parts but I am asking about a comprehensive list that shows descriptions and synonymous words. The wikipedia only gives words and some descriptions.

Comment: @Tek'eek, perhaps this is the place to create such a thing.  A wiki page could become what you describe.